# Unable to recover disk space Mac OS X EI Capitan

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I deleted one partition on my mac and now I am not able to recover that space.  `diskutil list` shows below output. Here I see total space is 500 GB and size of Yosemite(installed El Capitan on it) is 248 GB. So where is remaining 250 GB.

[image]

[image]

```
sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0

Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  976773167] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused    

sudo  gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0

      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  488816512         
  489226152  485912608      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  975138760    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  976408296     364839         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

Answer (score 1):

If backup is available then remove the recovery HD, resize the main volume to fill the remaining available space (since it appears the recovery HD is what is in the way of resizing) and then recreate the recovery HD with whatever you're comfortable with (suggestion https://github.com/MagerValp/Create-Recovery-Partition-Installer )

Comment: No CoreStorage logical volume groups found

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to fix your drive, all you need to do is enter the following command.

```
sudo  diskutil  resizevolume  /dev/disk0s2  R
```

The command should move `/dev/disk0s3` to the bottom of `disk0` while resizing `/dev/disk0s2` to maximum size. I am not sure if the `sudo` prefix is required.

> **In your case, '/dev/disk0s2' and '/dev/disk0s3' are already at the bottom of 'disk0', therefore the above command will not work**.

Fortunately, you should have enough space to clone your existing HFS+ formatted OS X volume labeled "Yosemite". You then can merge the partitions to recover all the lost space. The procedure is given below. To aid in understanding the steps, I preformed the procedure on a Sparse Disk Image. What you will encounter will differ slightly from the posted images. You will need to make the appropriate substitutions.

You will need to boot the Mac from either another drive or from OS X Internet Recovery. If you download the El Captitan OS X Installer from the Mac App Store, you can create a bootable flash drive. The steps are given at the Apple web site ["Create a bootable installer for OS X"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Using OS X Internet Recovery is described at the Apple web site ["About OS X Recovery"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314).

### The Procedure

1. Open the Terminal application. Enter the following commands.

   ```
   DISK=/dev/disk0
   sudo gpt -r show $DISK
   ```

   You should get the same output as posted in your question.
2. Next, enter the following commands. The integers given came from
   your posted question. These commands create a new partition
   (`disk0s4`) containing most of the missing free space.

   ```
   BEGIN=409640
   SIZE=488816512
   diskutil unmountdisk $DISK
   dd if=/dev/zero count=4 bs=512 seek=$BEGIN conv=notrunc of=$DISK
   diskutil unmountdisk $DISK
   gpt add -i 4 -b $BEGIN -s $SIZE -t hfs $DISK
   ```

   Close the window and quit the Terminal application.
3. Open the Disk Utility application and highlight the newly created
   partition. In my case, the device was `disk1s4` and label was
   "Untitled". Your device should be `disk0s4`.

   [image: 40]
4. From the menu bar, select "Edit->Restore...". Choose to restore from
   the HFS+ formatted OS X volume on the same drive. In my case, this
   volume was labeled "keep". Your volume should be labeled "Yosemite".
   Next, click on the "Restore" button. This step may take a while to
   complete.

   [image: 41]
5. When the pop up windows below appears, click on the "Done" button.
   The result should be a clone of both your HFS+ formatted OS X
   partition and your Recovery partition. Also, the partitions indices
   should be renumbered in ascending order.

   [image: 42]
6. With the newly created partition highlighted, click on the "Mount"
   button.

   [image: 43]
7. The label should change to the same as the volume you restored from.
   In your case this should be the label "Yosemite".

   [image: 44]

   Quit the Disk Utility application
8. Open the Terminal application. Enter the following commands. These
   commands will remove your original Recovery partition.

   ```
   DISK=/dev/disk0
   diskutil unmountdisk $DISK
   gpt remove -i 5 $DISK
   ```

   Close the window and quit the Terminal application.
9. Open the Disk Utility application. Highlight the drive you are
   working on and click the "Partition" button. Highlight the pie piece
   that will allow you to click on the "-" button. *There should be
   only one piece that will allow this.*

   [image: 48]
10. Click on the "-" button. The result should be similar to what is
     shown below. Next, click on the "Apply" button.

    [image: 49]
11. When the following pop up window appears, click on the "Done"
     button.

    [image: 46]
12. The result is shown below. You are finished. All the free space
     should now be recovered. This should also include the small pie
     piece shown in step 10.

    [image: 47]

Comment: It gives "Error: -69742: The requested size change for the target disk or a related disk is too small; please try a different disk or partition, or make a larger change"

Comment: @Akhil: I updated my answer.

Comment: I have edited the question with the results of coomands you asked.

Comment: I updated my answer with the new procedure.